# Problem about handle iAP succes on app store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

if user didn't have payment information before when iAP process is start app will be redirect user to the app store for take the user fill information of payment and when user is already complete it and payment is complete(get alert purchase is success) money was cut off and app store didn't redirect user back to the application and if user back to application noting happed.

SKPaymentTransactionObserver didn't call and user did't get any consumable(credit in application)

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
for transaction in transactions {
  switch transaction.transactionState {
  case .deferred:
    print("transactionState = deferred")
  case .purchasing:
    print("transactionState = purchasing")
  case .purchased:
    print("transactionState = purchased")
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    var receiptBase: String = ""
    if let receiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL {
      do {
        let receipt = try Data(contentsOf: receiptURL)
        let base64encodedReceipt = receipt.base64EncodedString()
        receiptBase = base64encodedReceipt
      } catch {
        receiptBase = ""
      }
    }
    //call api for add consumable to user
    buyCreditDelegate?.purchasedCredit(transactionId: transaction.transactionIdentifier ?? "", receiptId: receiptBase)
  case .failed:
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    if let delegate = self.buyCreditDelegate {
      delegate.cancelPurchases()
    }
  case .restored:
    print("transactionState = restored")
}
```

FYI:
My iAP is consumable.

How can i fix it and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line throughout:

```
SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
```

You need your observer to be a perpetual persistent object like the app delegate. Never remove it or the store cannot talk to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement :

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {

}
```

More on this from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/2877502-paymentqueue)

> This delegate method is called when the user starts an in-app purchase
>   in the App Store, and the transaction continues in your app.
>   Specifically, if your app is already installed, the method is called
>   automatically.
>
> If your app is not yet installed when the user starts the in-app
>   purchase in the App Store, the user gets a notification when the app
>   installation is complete. This method is called when the user taps the
>   notification. Otherwise, if the user opens the app manually, this
>   method is called only if the app is opened soon after the purchase was
>   started.